# GCP Cloud Functions will not display source code in Edit view

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've never encountered this issue before -- I can see the source code when simply viewing the Cloud Function, but when I go into edit I just get this error message:

[image: CF Error Msg Screenshot]

I wrote the function and am an owner of the GCP project, so there shouldn't be any permissions issues. I was not, however, the last person to edit the CF, so maybe there is an issue with that?

The GCP CF common errors page does not seem to have this issue documented: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting

Comment: Have you tried from an incognito window, or with another user? You can try that, and check with developers tools to see where is being stuck the request, if after that does not work, please share the detail of the request/response

Comment: I tried incognito window and the result was the same -- and another user is experiencing similar. When you say developer tools, do you mean the logs?

Comment: @LeeWerner, did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope. I can download the code in a zip file, though, and deploy via the gcloud SDK (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy), so I may just do that. Bummer that I can't change the code in the in-line editor though.

Comment: same here, any updates on solution guys?

Comment: same problem here!